# How to make Jenkins step move on and don't wait for a process to finish on Windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following steps in my Jenkinsfile

```
    stages {
        stage('Start & Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Start Server Tests') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                                groovyFile.startServer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Execute Tests') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                                groovyFile.executeTests()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            groovyFile.stopServer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

groovyFile.startServer() and groovyFile.executeTests() execute a maven instruction from my project.

startServer call a batch file that runs something similar to "java mypackge.MyServer start"

executeTests execute the integration tests usging the started server.

My problem is: once the tests are finished the server is still running and Jenkins keeps there hanging until I manually kill the server. I want that when the tests are done the scrip goes to "post" and the script stop the server.

I already tried to add "start /b" to the batch file that stars the server but without success.

The pipeline is running on Jenkins Slave using the javaagent in a Windows laptop.

Is there a way to say to Jenkins: "don't wait the stage 'Start Server Tests' to finish, just move on to the next stage outside 'Start & Run Tests'" ?

I you can see that I'm running the stages in parallel but this wasn't enough to move to the next stage and stop